# Call function at program initialization time

Tags: c++, templates, factory-pattern, template-meta-programming

So I'd like to be able to call a function at initialization time. It's a void function, but I want the side effects (updating a factory function table, in this case) to be in place by the time `main()` is called. Right now what I'm doing is just returning an int and initializing a static variable with it:

```
//Factory inherits from FactoryBase
class FactoryBase
{
    ...
private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, FactoryBase*> factoryTable;
public:
    template<class C>
    static int addClass(const std::string& name)
    {
        factoryTable[name] = new Factory<C>;
        return 0;
    }
};
...
int Foo::uselessStaticInt = FactoryBase::addClass<Foo>("foo");
//class Foo is now associated with the string "foo"
```

Is there a way I can call the static function without needing a static int?

I can post the complete source for the Factory classes, but what I'm more interested in is the compile-time or initialization-time function call

Comment: How could an inherently dynamic structure (like an `unordered_map`) be populated at compile-time?

Comment: I think you mean to say at program initialization time (before `main()`), not at compile-time.

Comment: Yes. Essentially at initialization-time, although it's functionally indistinguishable from compile-time. Fixed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the you can simply write `FactoryBase::addClass<Foo>("foo");` on a global level without writing `int Foo::uselessStaticInt = `. However, I can't guarantee that no compiler will optimise this away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was correctly pointed out by @interjay you are actually calling your function at initialization time (the time when static objects are initialized), not at compile time. AFAIK you won't be able to do this without having a static object. You might do this in the constructor of some static object though which might make the code look slightly simpler:

```
ClassRegister<Foo> fooRegister("foo"); // Call FactoryBase::addClass<Foo>("foo")
                                       // in the constructor of ClassRegister<Foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use an auxiliary registrator class, along with a single, global instance:

**Header file `FactoryBase.hpp`:**

```
template <typename T> struct Registrator
{
    explicit Registrator(char const * s)
    {
        FactoryBase<T>::addClass(s);
    }
};
```

(This could be a public nested class in `FactoryBase` if you prefer.)

**Translation unit:**

```
#include <FactoryBase.hpp>
#include <Foo.hpp>

namespace
{
    Registrator<Foo> fooRegistrator("foo");
}
```